# Magento 2.3.0 : Admin panel mass status action change after not updated in custom module grid record

Tags: module, magento2.3.0, massaction, status

I am using Magento 2.3.0 and I create custom module for video gallery in admin side module grid mass action change status after not updated in grid but message comes on successfully updated. If any one know how to debug and fix it.

below screenshot share for issue comes

[image]

```
<?php
namespace CustomModule\Videogallery\Block\Adminhtml\Videogallery;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\videogalleryFactory
     */
    protected $_videogalleryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\Status
     */
    protected $_status;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\videogalleryFactory $videogalleryFactory
     * @param \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\VideogalleryFactory $VideogalleryFactory,
        \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\Status $status,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_videogalleryFactory = $VideogalleryFactory;
        $this->_status = $status;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('postGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('video_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(false);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('post_filter');
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_videogalleryFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'video_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'video_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );



                $this->addColumn(
                    'video_name',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Video Name'),
                        'index' => 'video_name',
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'link',
                    [
                        'header' => __('link'),
                        'index' => 'link',
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'sort',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Sort By'),
                        'index' => 'sort',
                    ]
                );


                        $this->addColumn(
                            'status',
                            [
                                'header' => __('Status'),
                                'index' => 'status',
                                'type' => 'options',
                                'options' => \CustomModule\Videogallery\Block\Adminhtml\Videogallery\Grid::getOptionArray5()
                            ]
                        );





        //$this->addColumn(
            //'edit',
            //[
                //'header' => __('Edit'),
                //'type' => 'action',
                //'getter' => 'getId',
                //'actions' => [
                    //[
                        //'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        //'url' => [
                            //'base' => '*/*/edit'
                        //],
                        //'field' => 'video_id'
                    //]
                //],
                //'filter' => false,
                //'sortable' => false,
                //'index' => 'stores',
                //'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                //'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            //]
        //);



           $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('videogallery/*/exportCsv', ['_current' => true]),__('CSV'));
           $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('videogallery/*/exportExcel', ['_current' => true]),__('Excel XML'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {

        $this->setMassactionIdField('video_id');
        //$this->getMassactionBlock()->setTemplate('CustomModule_Videogallery::videogallery/grid/massaction_extended.phtml');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('videogallery');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('videogallery/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            ]
        );

        $statuses = $this->_status->getOptionArray();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'status',
            [
                'label' => __('Change status'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('videogallery/*/massStatus', ['_current' => true]),
                'additional' => [
                    'visibility' => [
                        'name' => 'status',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'class' => 'required-entry',
                        'label' => __('Status'),
                        'values' => $statuses
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );


        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('videogallery/*/index', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param \CustomModule\Videogallery\Model\videogallery|\Magento\Framework\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {

        return $this->getUrl(
            'videogallery/*/edit',
            ['video_id' => $row->getId()]
        );

    }


        static public function getOptionArray5()
        {
            $data_array=array(); 
            $data_array[1]='Enabled';
            $data_array[0]='Disabled';
            return($data_array);
        }
        static public function getValueArray5()
        {
            $data_array=array();
            foreach(\CustomModule\Videogallery\Block\Adminhtml\Videogallery\Grid::getOptionArray5() as $k=>$v){
               $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
            }
            return($data_array);

        }


}
```

Comment: Are you running though cloudflare? try reindexing your site and running flush cache

Comment: Did you checked if status got updated in database ?

Comment: @AbdulPathan yes status update when i go to edit single record after status change save in database

Comment: but in mass action select any record after change status not updated

Comment: could you please add your massAction code in the question ?

Comment: possible to add mass action code here.

Comment: @AnasMansuri added

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved in controller got to `CustomModule/Videogallery/Controller/Adminhtml/videogallery/massstatus.php` inside execute function

```
$post->setIsActive($status)->save();
```

change to

```
$post->setStatus($status)->save();
```

After clear flush issue resolved.

Comment: thanks for upvote